# How to force the reconnection with MongoDB when I lose and recover the internet connection

Tags: flutter, session, synchronization, realm, mongodb-atlas

The problem I'm having is that when I lose internet connection and get it back, it takes too long to reconnect, so I used Session.pause() and Session.resume() to force a reconnection. The problem is that since the last update of the domain package in flutter (realm: 1.4.0) Session.pause() and Session.resume() no longer work. Is there any other way to force the reconnection when I lose the connection and recover it?

I haven't been able to test much since the update came out 5 days ago and I can't find anyone who is having the same problem or information about it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question is vague. *it takes too long* - how long is too long? When our app disconnects and then reconnects it only takes a second or so for Realm to start syncing. Is 1 second too long? Do you have some example code that duplicates the issue? Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)